# After Drupal update show Errors

Tags: php, drupal

I've updated a Drupal from version 7.2 to version 7.26. 
After do that I've some errors:

```
 throw new EntityMalformedException (Missing bundle property on entity of type taxonomy_term)
```

It appears in file common . inc:

```
if (!isset($entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']}) || $entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']} === '') {
```

I insert some "echos" to see when is shown this message, and I get this:

```
var_dump( $info['entity keys']);

array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "tid"
  ["bundle"]=>
  string(23) "vocabulary_machine_name"
  ["label"]=>
  string(4) "name"
  ["revision"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

    array(4) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(3) "tid"
      ["bundle"]=>
      string(23) "vocabulary_machine_name"
      ["label"]=>
      string(4) "name"
      ["revision"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }

var_dump( $info);



  array(22) {
  ["label"]=>
  string(22) "Término de taxonomía"
  ["controller class"]=>
  string(22) "TaxonomyTermController"
  ["base table"]=>
  string(18) "taxonomy_term_data"
  ["uri callback"]=>
  string(17) "taxonomy_term_uri"
  ["fieldable"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["entity keys"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "tid"
    ["bundle"]=>
    string(23) "vocabulary_machine_name"
    ["label"]=>
    string(4) "name"
    ["revision"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["bundle keys"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["bundle"]=>
    string(12) "machine_name"
  }
  ["bundles"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["pais"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["label"]=>
      string(7) "Regions"
      ["admin"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["path"]=>
        string(58) "admin/structure/taxonomy/%taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name"
        ["real path"]=>
        string(29) "admin/structure/taxonomy/pais"
        ["bundle argument"]=>
        int(3)
        ["access arguments"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(19) "administer taxonomy"
        }
      }
      ["rdf_mapping"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["rdftype"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(12) "skos:Concept"
        }
        ["name"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["predicates"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(10) "rdfs:label"
            [1]=>
            string(14) "skos:prefLabel"
          }
        }
        ["description"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["predicates"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(15) "skos:definition"
          }
        }
        ["vid"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["predicates"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(13) "skos:inScheme"
          }
          ["type"]=>
          string(3) "rel"
        }
        ["parent"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["predicates"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(12) "skos:broader"
          }
          ["type"]=>
          string(3) "rel"
        }
      }
    }
    ["auto_created_voc38877"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["label"]=>
      string(10) "Provincias"
      ["admin"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["path"]=>
        string(58) "admin/structure/taxonomy/%taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name"
        ["real path"]=>
        string(46) "admin/structure/taxonomy/auto_created_voc38877"
        ["bundle argument"]=>
        int(3)
        ["access arguments"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(19) "administer taxonomy"
        }
      }
      ["rdf_mapping"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["rdftype"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(12) "skos:Concept"
        }
        ["name"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["predicates"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(10) "rdfs:label"
            [1]=>
            string(14) "skos:prefLabel"
          }
        }
        ["description"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["predicates"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(15) "skos:definition"
          }
        }
        ["vid"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["predicates"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(13) "skos:inScheme"
          }
          ["type"]=>
          string(3) "rel"
        }
        ["parent"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["predicates"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(12) "skos:broader"
          }
          ["type"]=>
          string(3) "rel"
        }
      }
    }
    ["busquedas_destacadas_"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["label"]=>
      string(21) "Búsquedas destacadas"
      ["admin"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["path"]=>
        string(58) "admin/structure/taxonomy/%taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name"
        ["real path"]=>
        string(46) "admin/structure/taxonomy/busquedas_destacadas_"
        ["bundle argument"]=>
        int(3)
        ["access arguments"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(19) "administer taxonomy"
        }
      }
      ["rdf_mapping"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["rdftype"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(12) "skos:Concept"
        }
        ["name"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["predicates"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(10) "rdfs:label"
            [1]=>
            string(14) "skos:prefLabel"
          }
        }
        ["description"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["predicates"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(15) "skos:definition"
          }
        }
        ["vid"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["predicates"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(13) "skos:inScheme"
          }
          ["type"]=>
          string(3) "rel"
        }
        ["parent"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["predicates"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(12) "skos:broader"
          }
          ["type"]=>
          string(3) "rel"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["view modes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["full"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["label"]=>
      string(34) "Página de términos de taxonomía"
      ["custom settings"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
  }
  ["static cache"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["field cache"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["load hook"]=>
  string(18) "taxonomy_term_load"
  ["translation"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["schema_fields_sql"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["base table"]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "tid"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "vid"
      [2]=>
      string(4) "name"
      [3]=>
      string(11) "description"
      [4]=>
      string(6) "format"
      [5]=>
      string(6) "weight"
      [6]=>
      string(8) "language"
      [7]=>
      string(9) "i18n_tsid"
    }
  }
  ["token type"]=>
  string(4) "term"
  ["access callback"]=>
  string(31) "entity_metadata_taxonomy_access"
  ["creation callback"]=>
  string(29) "entity_metadata_create_object"
  ["save callback"]=>
  string(18) "taxonomy_term_save"
  ["deletion callback"]=>
  string(20) "taxonomy_term_delete"
  ["view callback"]=>
  string(27) "entity_metadata_view_single"
  ["form callback"]=>
  string(34) "entity_metadata_form_taxonomy_term"
  ["configuration"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

I supposed this is related with something missing in the database. But I can't find it.

Any help, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly did you update your drupal installation? Did you run `update.php` already?

Comment: First, I updated all modules that we have installed, all with update.php option. After that I upload the Drupal Core and done update.php as well.

Comment: @CBroe I found some tables (field_data_field_g_b_i) that are empty. Could be this?